# R: Getting whisker to loop over a list with unknown names

Tags: r, templating, r-whisker

I'm trying to use [Whisker](https://github.com/edwindj/whisker) for HTML-templating in R, but seem to run into problems that should be an easy task for the package. All I want to do is to use [sections](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) to loop over a list, with the only problem that I cannot know and therefore specify the names of its elements:

```
library(whisker)

hash <- list(
  people = list(
    a = list(
      first = "john",
      last = "johnsson"
    ),
    b = list(
      first = "peter",
      last = "petersson"
    ),
    c = list(
      first = "steve",
      last = "stevesson"
    )
  ),
  stuff = c(1:5)
)

template <- "
{{#people}}
<h1>Hello {{first}}</h1>
{{/people}}
"

result <- whisker::whisker.render(template = template, data = hash)
print(HTML(result))
```

Expected output:

```
<h1>Hello john</h1>
<h1>Hello peter</h1>
<h1>Hello steve</h1>
```

I tried using `{{#.}}` and `.` in all possible constellations, but no luck. This should be a basic requirement of a templating package and I refuse to believe that it isn't possible :S

Any good alternatives to whisker in that case?
Thanks

Comment: This seems to work if your `people` list is unnamed, for example: `hash <- list(people = list(list(first = "john", last = "johnsson"), list(first = "peter", last = "petersson"), list(first = "steve", last = "stevesson")), stuff = 1:5)`. It looks like a named list is not treated as a collection. If you don't think that's the right behavior, you might consider [filing an issue with the package maintainer](https://github.com/edwindj/whisker/issues/)

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that named lists appear to be the issue. Just filed an issue. thx

Comment: I have what I think is a similar issue. I don't know anything about 'sections'. I am finding the whisker documentation (README) rather inadequate. Filed at github: https://github.com/edwindj/whisker/issues/31